# Bash uses Python from Anaconda even it's deactivated

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, conda

**Summary:** Even I deactivate conda environment with `conda deactivate`, when I type `python` (or `python3`) on bash, python from conda starts.

**Background:** Normally I use `pipenv` to handle python dependencies. But earlier I have installed conda too, to train some ML models with GPU, because I couln't manage run GPU using pipenv.

But I don't really want to use both conda and pipenv, so I decided to get rid of conda to see if I manage to run GPU only using pipenv.

But when I try to deactivate conda and work with default python, it still there:

```
(base) user@tower:~$ conda deactivate
user@tower:~$ python
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 30 2018, 01:22:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
user@tower:~$ python3
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 30 2018, 01:22:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

What do you suggest, can I try to run some python code without using conda?
If I can't, how can I completely get rid of conda?

I am open to any advice.

**Info 1:**
Output of `$PATH` before and after deactivating it are the same as:

```
-bash: /home/foouser/.local/bin:/home/foouser/.local/bin:/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin:/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin:/home/foouser/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/foouser/.vimpkg/bin: No such file or directory
```

Anaconda section in `~/.bashrc`:

```
# added by Anaconda3 2018.12 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/foouser/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/foouser/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

# added by Anaconda3 installer
export PATH="/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/home/foouser/.local/bin:/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin:/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin:/home/foouser/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/foouser/.vimpkg/bin"
```

**Info 2:**
Output of `which -a python`:

```
/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

**Edit-1:** Edited `bashrc` after suggestion:

```sh
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export PATH="/home/foouser/.local/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda3 2018.12 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/foouser/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/foouser/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

# added by Anaconda3 installer
# export PATH="/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

# export PATH="$PATH:/home/foouser/.vimpkg/bin"
# export PATH="/home/foouser/.local/bin:$PATH"
# export PATH="/home/foouser/.local/bin:/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin:/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin:/home/foouser/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/foouser/.vimpkg/bin"
```

Comment: You mean you want to change default python? (As I understand, you have rewritten your default python with python from Anaconda, right?) Did you try to google how to change default python on your OS? Here is an example for Debian https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux

Comment: Please provide output of  `which -a python`.

Comment: I edited the question to provide information you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the following lines, which go against [the post-Conda v.4.4 best practices](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.4.0) (i.e., don't manually manipulate `PATH` to add Conda):

```
# added by Anaconda3 installer
export PATH="/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/home/foouser/.local/bin:/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin:/home/foouser/anaconda3/bin:/home/foouser/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/foouser/.vimpkg/bin"
```

The first one should be deleted altogether. The second one should have all the paths containing `anaconda3` removed. Also, it is completely overwriting your original `PATH`. You should rework it so that only what you need to manually add is either prepended, e.g.,

```
export PATH="/home/foouser/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

or appended, e.g.,

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/foouser/.vimpkg/bin"
```

I would also move this to before the `# >>> conda init >>>` section.

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay. I added the question "Edit-1". But it still uses pyrhon from conda  even deactivated

Comment: @emremrah I just noticed that `eval` and `export` in the conda init section have `\\` before them. Try deleting those slashes. I recently saw someone reporting that as a bug in some systems.

Comment: That's actually seem to work! Now when I deactivate conda, I can start python2 and python3 interpreter individually, without conda. Thanks a lot

Comment: Also, im a bit confused too. Can you head me an article or something to get used to Ubuntu file system? Like what these `/bin /dev /usr /var` directories for, why are they seperated? These sort of information would be really helpful.

Comment: Ok I just found this: `https://www.linux.com/tutorials/linux-filesystem-explained/`, thanks a lot. Still, a source from you will be appreciated.